# How to attach html report with mail notification in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Here i have created Jenkins server with Bitbucket cloud. I want to attach index.html file then send to user by mail notification. But I couldn't make properly. I dont know where im wrong. can any one tell me the steps with screen shot to attach html file with mail notification?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 (If index.html is inside the slave box)**

Add Post-Build step --> Enable Email Notification --> Attachments [Text Box]
Inside the attachement textbox provided, you can give the path of your Index.html file.

[image]

**Method 2 (If index.html is outside the slave box)**

Provide the content of your html file in the $DEFAULT_CONTENT provided under Email notification (above picture)

Comment: i already gave the path of index file..its attached too..but when user access the html file from mail then it goes to jenkins server. But i want just html file access. Please tell me configuration. Im new to this server.

Comment: You didnt mention this problem in your question. You question should be clear !

Comment: Please update the question and put a sample content of index.html in the question.

Comment: im not using master/slave in jenkins. Just using single server on aws. I have created jenkins on that.

Comment: Ok. Let me know the content of the html file.

Comment: I already provide file location in default content in editable mail notification. test_bucket is my project (job) name. unitproj/ is unit test folder name. /coverage folder having the index file. This /coverage folder automatically will create once unit test run.          ${FILE,path="test_bitbucket/unitproj/coverage/client/lcov-report/index.html"}

Comment: You have mentioned `but when user access the html file from mail then it goes to jenkins server. But i want just html file access` . To know that exact issue, you should show us the content of the html file.

Comment: content of html file mean? its too large file.

Comment: Hmm.. If attachment is attached and could see in the mail, the process from Jenkins is done correctly. Now, the issue is while clicking on the attachment it goes to jenkins. Which means there should be links to the Jenkins server. Do check your index html file

Comment: Try one thing : Download it manually (or copy from Jenkins) to your machine. And double click and open to see what happens.

Comment: So, an option is to change the file extension. Do a bash-script inside your jenkins to make a zip file (containing index.html) and provide the path of that zip file. That will work as you expected.